# can you give me a hand using list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to store basketball player information, and the things I want to store are Player name and Player height.
Also, I want to be able to iterate using loops through that list, so therefore I made a list of dictionaries to achieve that? I am not sure if everything is correct?

The code:

```py
print("Basketball players ranker")
p_num = int(2)
player_info = [{
    "Name":[],
    "height":[]
}]

for i in range(p_num):
    print("please enter player name")
    player_name = input()
    print("please enter player height")
    player_height = int(input())
    
    player_info.append(["Name"].append(player_name))
    player_info.append(["height"].append(player_height))
    
    

counter = int(0)
print("so we got the folowing info")
for i in player_info:
    print(player_info[counter].get("Name"))
    print(player_info[counter].get("height"))
    counter +=1
```

Output example:

```py
Basketball players ranker
please enter player name
pl1
please enter player hight
10
please enter player name
pl2
please enter player hight
20
so we got the folowing info
[]
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\projects\python_learning\python-exirsizes\x3.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(player_info[counter].get("Name"))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
PS D:\python\projects\python_learning\python-exirsizes>
```

I think from my code above you should understand what I am trying to achieve and if I am totally wrong please provide me the corrected code if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the code in your first for loop, you append data inconsistantly.

```py
print("Basketball players ranker")
p_num = 2
player_info = list()

for i in range(p_num):
    player_name = input("please enter player name: ")
    player_height = int(input("please enter player height: "))
    
    player_info.append({
        "Name": player_name,
        "height": player_height
    })

print("so we got the following info")
for i in range(len(player_info)):
    print(player_info[i].get("Name"))
    print(player_info[i].get("height"))

# Or

for player in player_info:
    print(player.get("Name"))
    print(player.get("height"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, a quick question though
what is the purpose of 'player" in for loop? 



print("so we got the following info")
for i, *player* in enumerate(player_info):
    print(player_info[i].get("Name"))
    print(player_info[i].get("Height"))
```

Comment: Well technically it does nothing here. I've added an alternative for you to understand it better. The way you write your code disturbed me ^^'. (enumerate returns a tuple with the index and the element at the index)